# Regular Expression for no repeating special characters (C#)

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to regular expressions and need a regular expression for address, in which user cannot enter repeating special characters such as: `.....` or `,,,...///` etc and none of the special characters could be entered more than 5 times in the string.

```
...,,,....// =>No Match
Street no. 40. hello. =>Match
```

Thanks in advance!
I have tried this:

```
([a-zA-Z]+|[\s\,\.\/\-]+|[\d]+)|(\(([\da-zA-Z]|[^)^(]+){1,}\))
```

It selects all alphanumeric n some special character with no empty brackets.

Comment: what about this `Street no....///40. hello...` Is address multi-line or all in single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regular expression string to detect **invalid** strings is:

```
[^\w \-\r\n]{2}|(?:[\w \-]+[^\w \-\r\n]){5}
```

As [C# string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090.aspx) (regular and verbatim):

```
"[^\\w \\-\\r\\n]{2}|(?:[\\w \\-]+[^\\w \\-\\r\\n]){5}"

@"[^\w \-\r\n]{2}|(?:[\w \-]+[^\w \-\r\n]){5}"
```

It is much easier to find a string than to validate if a string does not contain ...

It can be checked with this expression if the string entered by the user is invalid because of a match of 2 special characters in sequence OR 5 special characters used in the string.

Explanation:

`[^`...`]` ... a negative character class definition which matches any character NOT being one of the characters listed within the square brackets.

`\w` ... a word character which is either a letter, a digit or an underscore.

The next character is simply a space character.

`\-` ... the hyphen character which must be escaped with a backslash within square brackets as otherwise the hyphen character would be interpreted as "FROM x TO z" (except when being the first or the last character within the square brackets).

`\r` ... carriage return

`\n` ... line-feed

Therefore `[^\w \-\r\n]` finds a character which is NOT a letter, NOT a digit, NOT an underscore, NOT a space, NOT a hyphen, NOT a carriage return and also NOT a line-feed.

`{2}` ... the preceding expression must match 2 such characters.

So with the expression `[^\w \-\r\n]{2}` it can be checked if the string contains 2 special characters in a sequence which makes the string invalid.

`|` ... OR

`(?:`...`)` ... none marking group needed here for applying the expression inside with the multiplier `{5}` at least 5 times.

`[`...`]` ... a positive character class definition which matches any character being one of the characters listed within the square brackets.

`[\w \-]+` ... find a word character, or a space, or a hyphen 1 or more times.

`[^\w \-\r\n]` ... and next character being NOT a word character, space, hyphen, carriage return or line-feed.

Therefore `(?:[\w \-]+[^\w \-\r\n]){5}` finds a string with 5 "special" characters between "standard" characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Negative lookahead construction` that asserts what is invalid to match. Its format is (?! ... )

For your case you can try something like this:

This will not match the input string if it has 2 or more consecutive dots, commas or slashes (or any combination of them)

```
(?!.*[.,\/]{2}) ... rest of the regex
```

This will not match the input string if it has more than 5 characters 'A'.

```
(?!(.*A.*){5}) ... rest of the regex
```

This will match everything except your restrictions. Repplace last part (.*) with your regex.

```
^(?!.*[.,\/]{2})(?!(.*\..*){5})(?!(.*,.*){5})(?!(.*\/.*){5}).*$
```

Note: This regex may no be optimized. It may be faster if you use loop to iterate over string characters and count their occurences.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?![^,./-]*([,./-])\1)(?![^,./-]*([,./-])(?:[^,./-]*\2){4})[ \da-z,./-]+$
```

In C#:

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(yourString, @"^(?![^,./-]*([,./-])\1)(?![^,./-]*([,./-])(?:[^,./-]*\2){4})[ \da-z,./-]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The negative lookahead `(?![^,./-]*([,./-])\1)` asserts that it is not possible to match any number of special chars, followed by one special char (captured to Group 1) followed by the same special char (the `\1` backreference)
- The negative lookahead `(?![^,./-]*([,./-])(?:[^,./-]*\2){4})` ` asserts that it is not possible to match any number of special chars, followed by one special char (captured to Group 2), then any non-special char and that same char from Group 2, four times (five times total)
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: Added explanation, let me know if you have questions. :)

Comment: Your regex will fail for string with `more than 5 occurrences of special characters` if there is one special character and then following 5 or more other special characters - example `a,b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i`. However +1 for the good ideas.

Comment: @ViktorBahtev Yes, that was exactly what I aimed to do. :) That was my understanding of the OP's requirement: it doesn't matter where the special chars are in the string. See for instance `...,,,....// =>No Match`. But I may have misunderstood.

Comment: Oops sorry. There is ambiguous explanation and example in the question.